# How do deal with multicollinearity, endogeneity and interpret the interaction terms in a panel dataset?

Tags: interaction, multicollinearity, mediation, endogeneity, generalized-moments

The model

ŷ = b0 + b1X1 + b2X2 + b3X1X2

ŷ =company financial performance metric
X1 = carbon emissions
X2 = carbon assurance
X1X2 = interaction term

The issues:

Let’s say:
•   X1 + X2 are related (but there is no perfect multicollinearity)
•   X2 is endogenous

The questions that I would like to address based on the model above
•   What is the main effect of X1 cause ŷ ?
•   What is the moderating effect of X2 in the relationship between X1 & ŷ?
•   What is the mediating effect of X2 in the relationship between X1 & ŷ?

The possible solution to address the issues and questions that need to be reliably answered?
•   Can we use a 2SLS regression to deal with the issues by finding a Z variable for X2 that is not related with ŷ?
•   Can we use a dynamic GMM model to deal with the endogeneity issues but will the dynamic GMM model deal with the multicollinearity between X1 + X2?
•   Will either of the above solutions allow the researcher to interpret the coefficients against X1 and  X1X2 appropriately?

STATA Commands to use?
For a 2SLS – would you use ivregress
For a dynamic GMM would you use xtdpdml or xtdpdsys